# Cannot sort the value in asc order as per key using PHP

Tags: php, sorting

I need to sort my array value in asc order using PHP. Here is my code:

```
$data=[
  {"restaurant_name":"The Garage Sports Bar","distance":"0.48Km"},
  {"restaurant_name":"A&P Chinese Food Express","distance":"8.81Km"},
  {"restaurant_name":"Green Chilli","distance":"19.37Km"},
  {"restaurant_name":"Pulcinella - Authentic Napoletana Pizza","distance":"1.31Km"}
]
```

I have above data to sort in asc order. My PHP code is below:

```
$sortArray = array();
foreach($data as $person){
    foreach($person as $key=>$value){
if(!isset($sortArray[$key])){
 $sortArray[$key] = array(); 
}
$sortArray[$key][] = $value;
    }
}
$orderby = "distance";
array_multisort($sortArray[$orderby],SORT_ASC,$data);
```

After sorting it I am getting the following output.

```
$data=[{"restaurant_name":"The Garage Sports Bar","distance":"0.48Km"},{"restaurant_name":"Pulcinella - Authentic Napoletana Pizza","distance":"1.31Km"},{"restaurant_name":"Green Chilli","distance":"19.37Km"},{"restaurant_name":"A&P Chinese Food Express","distance":"8.81Km"}]
```

But it could not be sort properly in ASC order.

Comment: post your correct $data array value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the sorting type as `SORT_NUMERIC` in the `array_multisort` function as follows

```
array_multisort($sortArray[$orderby],SORT_ASC,SORT_NUMERIC,$dataA);
```

This will give you the desired result.